# Webpack 2 with historyApiFallback Not Working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-2

I keep getting `Cannot GET /task` I tried to modify my webpack with solutions I found here but I still get it.

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }, {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: '/index.html'
        },
        stats: true,
        inline: true,
        progress: true
    }
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: './src/index.html'})]
}
```

Comment: you are getting this error when run devServer?

Comment: @YuriRamos no say if my url is like "http://localhost:8080". I click on a button and it goes to  "http://localhost:8080/grades". If I then make a change in my solution dev server will rerender the page and this is when I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think client gets `index.html` only when path is `/`.

Try to use this setting.

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
}
```

Comment: Weird, I thought I tried that but now it seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: hey, one more thing though I started to add parameters to my routes like  <Route path='/task/:id' component={TaskContainerComponent}/> but this historyapiFallback does not work anymore. I don't get a 404 but I get a white screen.

Comment: @chobo2 The same setting works fine in my app with this kind of path ``/task/:id``. I think you have a problem in your route or component. Component isn't rendered so you get a white screen.

Comment: Hmm maybe, not sure what though. I do see a 404 for my bundle.js so it is not getting any of my javascript when I do something /task/1. Not sure how to tell my routing to handle that.

Comment: I think i needed to add a publicPath of "/" as then my bundle src url gets built as  src="/app.bundle.js" and not  src="app.bundle.js"

Comment: Maybe. Did ``publicPath`` help?